# SignalR as WCF web socket service

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to host SignalR as a part of WCF websocket service and not as a part of ASP.net web site. I am aware about pushing mesage from a web service to signalR clients but is it also possible tht when the socket connection is opened from browser it maps to a web serivce contract?

Comment: I am using a REST service hosted as signalR server and pushing data to one of the service method and the service push data to the signalR clients

Answer (score 5):

You can self-host the SignalR server:

Taken from (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs):

Getting Started
To get started, Install the following packages:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Hosting -pre
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener -pre
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin -pre

using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace SignalR.Hosting.Self.Samples
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://172.0.0.01:8080";

        using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // This will map out to http://localhost:8080/signalr by default
        // This means a difference in the client connection.

        app.MapHubs();
    }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can host the SignarR hub in any .Net application, like:

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Connect to the service
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/mysite");

    // Create a proxy to the chat service
    var chat = hubConnection.CreateProxy("chat");

    // Print the message when it comes in
    chat.On("addMessage", message => Console.WriteLine(message));

    // Start the connection
    hubConnection.Start().Wait();

    string line = null;
    while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Send a message to the server
        chat.Invoke("Send", line).Wait();
    }
}
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

If there any specific reason you want to use WCF? you can write your service as SignarR hub only.

Comment: I have a scenario where we need to push data from a windows service which is on a server other than web server. So I was thinking of having a WCF service where i can implement websocket/signalR and I can use that service on the browser to open up the socket connection which creates all the socket clients on the wcf service and also i can use the same wcf service  in the windows service to push data via the wcf service.

Comment: The above creates a SignalR client hub not a server. For a self hosting server see: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host