# Asp.Net : Best way to broadcast data from WCF service to Asp.Net client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-applications, real-time, signalr

I need to create a high-frequency realtime web application and I would like to know the best way for doing it!

A WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service needs to refresh browser clients (ASP.NET application) each seconds with fresh data (often with IE8).

I've think about 2 solutions : 
1. WCF Callback from WCF Service to Asp.Net Application server side and SignalR from ASP.NET Application server side to ASP.NET Application client side.

1. SignalR from WCF service to Asp.NET Application client side but is it possible??? If yes, how because I just found tutorials with communication between Asp.net server side and cient side and never with signalR as server hosted in a WCF.

Documentation I found is :

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/12/06/Using-SignalR-to-broadcast-a-slide-deck.aspx
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr#serverloop

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post can help: [SignalR as WCF web socket service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562859/signalr-as-wcf-web-socket-service) :

> ...
>
> You can self-host the SignalR server:
>
> Taken from (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs):

Comment: I gonna try it and answer here after testing !